# What is the smallest possible value of NUMBER

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to know what the smallest possible value is for a default number column.

I can see from the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#number) that the default precision is number(38,0), so I would assume therefore that the minimum allowed value is

-99999999999999999999999999999999999999

however the documentation doesn't specify exactly what the limits are.

Is this correct?

Comment: wow, this question is really not how I read small to mean, as -9999... is a really large negative number, in my mind, not a small number, with small being something like 0.00001 at which point the question becomes a function of precision you choose. But that is not question. Out of interest, what is the nature of needing to understand the limits?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I want to try and work out a sensible place to seed my identity columns from. I think it's further complicated by the way Snowflake holds the data, the longer the value, the more space your column takes up

Comment: why not go with the standard of 0? because if you are putting a trillion rows in, thus need that width, starting at -1 trillion saves you nothing, and by the time you have 100 trillion rows you probably have other scaling problems than optimizing a column width. Aka you and overthinking that wrong part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, the minimum number you can insert is:

-99999999999999999999999999999999999999

I gave it a try and here are the results.

```
create temporary table test_db.public.test_table (col1 number);
insert into test_db.public.test_table values (-99999999999999999999999999999999999999); -- This works fine
insert into test_db.public.test_table values (-999999999999999999999999999999999999999); -- this errors
```

The second SQL with 39 precision produced the following error message from Snowflake:

> SQL compilation error: Error line 1 at position 48 Integer literal is out of representable range: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999